# How could I implement multiple members on a single donation?

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2007

I am making a database through access for a church.
Most of the time, couples tend to donate a sum but sometimes they may choose to donate individually for specific fundraiser events.

I am very rusty in MS Access so less VBA/SQL would be great. (Last time using access was in high school)

So far I have two rough tables, `tb|Contacts` and `tb|Donations`.
I have thought of changing the primary key in `tb|Donations` to `ContactID` and allowing `DonationID` to have duplicates but realised I wouldn't know how to entry forms for couple donations.

Would it be wiser to create a single Contact as a couple or is there an easier way that I am missing?

Comment: Perhaps need another table that associates contacts with donations? Access has a table feature called a multi-value field but I don't recommend using. A multi-value field creates that third table but hides it.

Comment: the question is too broad. Review Table normalization and Many to Many relationships.  There are several normalizations.  Couples being important you can either create a query to infer the couples from a PersonsDonations table (ManytoMany) or keep a couples table (PersonsPersons : ManytoMany).  Once you have normalized tables, click on each one and hit create form.  Play around with those forms.  There will be a couple ways to get the data entered with no VBA required.  Compare to the form you want to use to enter the data.  If you want use vba to combine the forms.  better form = better way